# Rails: Upload text file, preview, then save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, text-files

I want to upload text files that have several hundred lines in it. I want to present users a preview of the first 10 lines of the file, where they can adjust a format and then click process. After the click, I want to process the file based on the specified format and save the entries to the database. Finally the file should be deleted on the server side.

How could I do that? Is there a gem like paperclip for images to handle text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Ryan Bate's this cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Comment: yes, I'm doing it so, that I save the uploaded file into the tmp directory and then store the filename into the database. In the next step I read the file and give the user the ability to map the data to the database structure. thx!